# Nested views in Backbone.js - What is blocking my event handlers?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I created a simple Backbone app which creates tabs on the fly - loosely based on 
Chris Sterritt's blog article. However, I am unable to get past the second tab.  For some reason my event handler, which is bound to the "Submit" button on the second tab, never fires.

Apologies for the large code snippets.  This is as brief as I can make it.  Working on getting into jsfiddle...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dynamic jQuery UI Tabs with Backbone</title>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
          media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="stylesheets/zurb_foundation.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script id=Template1 type="text/template">
        <h4>Tab 1</h4>
        <h2> Tab 1 content here...</h2>
        <button id="submitTab1">Submit</button>
    </script>

    <script id=Template2 type="text/template">
        <h4>Tab 2</h4>
        <h2> Tab 2 content here...</h2>
        <button id="submitTab2">Submit</button>
    </script>

    <script id=Template3 type="text/template">
        <h4>Tab 3</h4>
        <h2> Tab 3 content here...</h2>
        <button id="submitTab3">Submit</button>
    </script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="javascript/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="javascript/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="eight columns">
            <div id="tab_wrapper">
                <ul id="tab_ul"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    "use strict";

    // Build our TabEx objects
    buildTabExUI();
```

app.js:

```
/*
 Contains the Backbone.js application logic.
 */

(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    // The TabExTab object
    window.TabExTab = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function () {
        },

        defaults: {
            name: "Name",
            contents: "Contents of Name"
        }

    });

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    window.ShowTab1 = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function () {
        },
    });


    window.ShowTab1View = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($('#Template1').html()),
        //template: _.template($('#Template1')),

        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template);
            this.delegateEvents();
            return this;
        },

        events: {
            'click #submitTab1': 'submitTab1',
        },

        // Bind events to the button clicks for the different templates...
        submitTab1: function(event){
            console.log("SubmitTab1 was clicked");
            event.preventDefault();
            $(location).attr('href','#showTab2');
        }

});


    //------------------------------------------------------------
    window.ShowTab2 = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function () {
        }
    });

    window.ShowTab2View = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($('#Template2').html()),
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template);
            this.delegateEvents();
            return this;
        },

        events: {
            'click #submitTab2': 'submitTab2'
        },

        submitTab2: function(event){
            console.log("SubmitTab2 was clicked");
            $(location).attr('href','#showTab2');
            event.preventDefault();
        }

    });


    //------------------------------------------------------------
    window.ShowTab3 = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function () {
        }
    });

    window.ShowTab3View = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($('#Template3').html()),
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template);
            this.delegateEvents();
            return this;
        },

        events: {
            'click #submitTab3': 'submitTab3'
        },

        // Bind events to the button clicks for the different templates...
        submitTab3: function(event){
            console.log("SubmitTab3 was clicked");
            $(location).attr('href','#showTab4');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });




    window.buildTabExUI = function () {

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // The view for a single TabExBlock object
        window.TabExTabView = Backbone.View.extend({

            initialize: function () {
                _.bindAll(this, 'render');
                this.model.bind('change', this.render);
            },

            render: function () {
                // add the actual content
                $("#tab_wrapper").append('<div id="tab_' + this.model.cid + '">');
                console.log("Model contents: " + this.model.get('contents'));

                // ask jQueryUI to add the tab to the bar
                $("#tab_wrapper").tabs("add", "#tab_" + this.model.cid, this.model.get('name'));

                return this;
            }
        });

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // The router
        window.TabExRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                '': 'home',
                'showTab2': 'showTab2',
                'showTab3': 'showTab3'
            },

            initialize: function () {
                this.inner = new window.ShowTab1View({model: window.ShowTab1});
            },

            home: function () {
                $('#tab_ul').empty();
                $('#tab_wrapper').empty();
                $('#tab_wrapper').append('<ul id="tab_ul"></ul>');

                // Set up the tab holder
                $("#tab_wrapper").tabs();

                // Create the first tab as the anchor for subsequent tabs
                var nt = new window.TabExTab({name: "Tab1 ", contents: "Show Tab 1"});
                var btv = new window.TabExTabView({model: nt});
                btv.render();

                console.log("Tab CID: " + "tab_" + btv.model.cid);

                //  This code creates the tab cid ( e.g. #tab_c2 ) using the reference values
                $("#tab_" + btv.model.cid).append(this.inner.template);
                console.log("EL: " + btv.$el.append(this.inner.$el));
                btv.$el.append(this.inner.$el);
                this.inner.render();
            },

            showTab2: function () {
                this.inner = new window.ShowTab2View({model: window.ShowTab2});

                var nt = new window.TabExTab({name: "Tab2 ", contents: "Show Tab 2"});
                var btv = new window.TabExTabView({model: nt});
                btv.render();

                var tabCID = "tab_" + btv.model.cid;
                console.log("Tab CID: " + tabCID);

                //  This code creates the tab cid ( e.g. #tab_c2 ) using the reference values
                $("#tab_" + btv.model.cid).append(this.inner.template);
                btv.$el.append(this.inner.$el);
                this.inner.render();

                // Select the new tab
                $("#tab_wrapper").tabs("select", "#" + tabCID);
            },


            showTab3: function () {
                this.inner = new window.ShowTab3View({model: window.ShowTab3});

                var nt = new window.TabExTab({name: "Tab3 ", contents: "Show Tab 3"});
                var btv = new window.TabExTabView({model: nt});
                btv.render();

                var tabCID = "tab_" + btv.model.cid;
                console.log("Tab CID: " + tabCID);

                //  This code creates the tab cid ( e.g. #tab_c2 ) using the reference values
                $("#tab_" + btv.model.cid).append(this.inner.template);
                btv.$el.append(this.inner.$el);
                this.inner.render();

                // Select the new tab
                console.log("Tab ID: ", "#tab_wrapper").tabs("select", "#" + tabCID);
                $("#tab_wrapper").tabs("select", "#" + tabCID);
            }


        });

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Kick off the application
        window.App = new TabExRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();

    }
```

})(jQuery);

I have tried this code in a few different browsers as well as WebStorm's debugger and am stumped!

Update: I have refactored my code where the events are moved into the View block.  Now even the first event does not fire.  I am learning Backbone and am really missing something here.

Comment: @Stack overflow has build in code editor like jsfiddle. Try to make it work there.

Comment: Your thingies are probably  not working because you're not using backbones event delegation. When you're using it use it properly.

Comment: There is no `#submitTab1` until that template has been rendered and that probably happens after you try to bind to it. Similarly for `#submitTab2` and `#submitTab3`. Rewrite your code to use the `events` in your Backbone views and things will go better.

Comment: Manky thanks @muistooshort!  That makes perfect sense and is by far the most constructive (read helpful) comment.   Kudos!

Comment: I updated my post to show refactored code which is still not working.

Comment: @muistooshort : you appear to know Backbone well.  Do you have any thoughts on my edited view code?

Comment: Setting up a runnable demo somewhere (such as jsfiddle.net, jsbin.com, or even as a code snippet in the question) would help clarify exactly what you're doing. `submitTab1` in a model is odd, view-ish things should be handled by views. `<button type="button">` is a good idea to avoid ending up with `<button type="submit">`. If you have to call `delegateEvents` you're almost always doing something wrong. I don't see anything rendering  `ShowTab1View` or adding its `el` to the page.

Comment: @muistooshort , many thanks!  I'll get something up online.  I appreciate the assist.  Long time developer, new to client-side JavaScript.    The `delegateEvents()` bit is so that the parent view can handle events from the child.   There seems currently to be a paucity of docs useful to the neophyte.  Most of goes too deep too fast with no "why" commentary.

Comment: @muistooshort - the rendering is happening in the app.js code.  The tab (outer view) is rendered and then it renders the inner view.  It will make more sense online...